# Reorganise expression as trigonometric polynomial

Tags: expression-manipulation, fourier-analysis

I have this expression (obtained with `Expand`):

```
A=-((Λa^3 BesselK[0,r Λa] Sin[2 ϕ])/(4 BesselK[0,Λa]))-(Λa^2 BesselK[1,r Λa] Sin[2 ϕ])/(2 r BesselK[0,Λa])-(Λa^3 BesselK[2,r Λa] Sin[2 ϕ])/(4 BesselK[0,Λa])+(Λa^3 BesselK[3,r Λa] Cos[ϕ+Subscript[ξ, 1]] Sin[2 ϕ] Subscript[D, 1])/(8 BesselK[1,Λa])-(Λa^2 BesselK[0,r Λa] Sin[ϕ-Subscript[ξ, 1]] Subscript[D, 1])/(8 r BesselK[1,Λa])-(Λa BesselK[1,r Λa] Sin[ϕ-Subscript[ξ, 1]] Subscript[D, 1])/(4 r^2 BesselK[1,Λa])+(3 Λa^3 BesselK[1,r Λa] Sin[ϕ-Subscript[ξ, 1]] Subscript[D, 1])/(16 BesselK[1,Λa])-(Λa^2 BesselK[2,r Λa] Sin[ϕ-Subscript[ξ, 1]] Subscript[D, 1])/(8 r BesselK[1,Λa])+(3 Λa^2 BesselK[0,r Λa] Sin[3 ϕ+Subscript[ξ, 1]] Subscript[D, 1])/(8 r BesselK[1,Λa])+(3 Λa BesselK[1,r Λa] Sin[3 ϕ+Subscript[ξ, 1]] Subscript[D, 1])/(4 r^2 BesselK[1,Λa])+(3 Λa^3 BesselK[1,r Λa] Sin[3 ϕ+Subscript[ξ, 1]] Subscript[D, 1])/(16 BesselK[1,Λa])+(3 Λa^2 BesselK[2,r Λa] Sin[3 ϕ+Subscript[ξ, 1]] Subscript[D, 1])/(8 r BesselK[1,Λa])+(Λa^3 BesselK[0,r Λa] Sin[2 ϕ] Subscript[ϵ, 1])/(4 BesselK[0,Λa])+(Λa^2 BesselK[1,r Λa] Sin[2 ϕ] Subscript[ϵ, 1])/(2 r BesselK[0,Λa])+(Λa^3 BesselK[2,r Λa] Sin[2 ϕ] Subscript[ϵ, 1])/(4 BesselK[0,Λa])
```

and I would like to simplify it in order to have the structure:

$\text{Coefficient}(A,\sin\phi) \sin(\phi)+\text{Coefficient}(A,\sin2\phi)\sin 2\phi+\text{etc.}$

How would I do this? `FullSimplify` and `Simplify` of course reduce everything too much.

Comment: Something like `FunctionExpand[TrigReduce[A]]`?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do with terms such as `Cos[ϕ + Subscript[ξ, 1]]`..

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Collect[A, Sin[_ ϕ - _] | Sin[_ ϕ + _] | Sin[_ ϕ] | Sin[ϕ - _] | Sin[ϕ] | Sin[ϕ + _]]
```

Comment: Simpler is Collect[A, _Sin]